# Should we add a legal link to the blog?

Tags: feature-request, blog

We recently talked in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2463568#2463568) about writing How-To's for the blog.  In a similar vein to this [question](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70/dangerous-answers), it's entirely possible that a reader of the blog may not have the ability to complete a project safely.

We talked about adding disclaimers to the entry, having a few people review the entry for safety concerns, etc, but we were still concerned about liability.  Does it make sense to add the [legal](http://stackexchange.com/legal) link to the footer of the blog, like every stackexchange page?  The Terms of Service seems to cover the legal ramifications from following the advice in a blog entry.

Answer (score 1):

[image]