# What to do with questions/answers that illustrate something dangerous?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dangerous answers](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70/dangerous-answers)

See: [How can I figure out why my light won't turn on?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/22149/how-can-i-figure-out-why-my-light-wont-turn-on/23288#23288)

Look at the answer.  This is beyond dangerous - it's stupid for numerous reasons.

I think we have a duty to remove such egregiously bad suggestions, not just down vote them.

In cases where it's a question/self-answer like this one, I think removing the entire topic is appropriate.

Thoughts?

Comment: See: http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/questions/70/dangerous-answers

Comment: I don't often vtc my own questions.  But there you go ;)

Comment: Haha, you could just delete it, but I'll close it for you if you want others to witness it.

Comment: Also relevant: http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/a/634/22

Comment: http://qkme.me/3sj6cs